# HTML/CSS Two Column Layout that Mobiilzes as One-Column Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I'm trying to make a two column layout with short lists of text on the left and photos on the right, like this...

LIST IMAGE

LIST IMAGE

LIST IMAGE

When viewed in a narrow browser window or on a mobile device, I want the images and lists to alternate, like so...

IMAGE

LIST

IMAGE

LIST

IMAGE

LIST

I figured I would just put the items in alternating order in the HTML and then float the images to the right at larger window sizes. This looks good for the mobile view, but the images line up with the headings in a weird way at larger browser window sizes, as you can see here:

http://allgoodeatslocal.com/links.html

I'm not sure how to do make this happen, other than having separate layouts for the two sizes...separate left (all the lists) and right (all the images) divs for full size viewing vs. alternating lists and images for small, mobile viewing.

Any better ideas?

Comment: Move your image inside `p`, wrap text into `span` and give `float: left` to that `span`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the media query, `@media`, to achieve this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Set a media query for a smaller resolution/screen and set the width of the list and image div to 100% of the container and they should stack.

Comment: They stack nicely on my mobile view (I don't think I set that up for this link) but I want everything to float all the way up in the left and right columns (I know there's no float up, but that's essentially what I want them to do) in the regular (non-mobile) view.